# AWS s3 listobjects with pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pagination

I want to implement pagination using aws s3. There are 500 files in object ms.files but i want to retrieve only 20 files at a time and next 20 next time and so on.

```
var params = {
  Bucket: 'mystore.in',
  Delimiter: '/',
  Prefix: '/s/ms.files/',
  Marker:'images',
};
s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
  else     console.log(data);          
});
```

Comment: "don't work if pagination is needed" - you haven't even tried to implement pagination here. It's clearly explained here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property

Comment: I tried passing the marker but did not work

Comment: well, show you're not working code.... you're not showing what you have tried

Comment: code is updated now with marker

Comment: Suspect you should start with MaxKeys: 20 and Marker: '', and then modify Marker on 2nd and subsequent iterations to contain the marker returned in the previous listObjects response.

Answer (score 19):

Came across this while looking to list all of the objects at once, if your response is truncated it gives you a flag `isTruncated = true` and a continuationToken for the next call

If youre on es6 you could do this,

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({});

const listAllContents = async ({ Bucket, Prefix }) => {
  // repeatedly calling AWS list objects because it only returns 1000 objects
  let list = [];
  let shouldContinue = true;
  let nextContinuationToken = null;
  while (shouldContinue) {
    let res = await s3
      .listObjectsV2({
        Bucket,
        Prefix,
        ContinuationToken: nextContinuationToken || undefined,
      })
      .promise();
    list = [...list, ...res.Contents];

    if (!res.IsTruncated) {
      shouldContinue = false;
      nextContinuationToken = null;
    } else {
      nextContinuationToken = res.NextContinuationToken;
    }
  }
  return list;
};
```

Comment: First of all, I just used your example, so thank you! I have been doing some reading up on how to use the spread operator. From what I understand , the line " list = [...list, ...res.Contents];" is basically reading the existing ...list array on each iteration of the while loop and copying it AND the new results of the call to s3.listObjectsV2 (in this case ...res.Content)?

Comment: looking back at the implementation I feel like `list.push(...res.Contents)` would be better, as it does not declare a new array every loop.


The line `list = []` is declaring a new array, and `...list` is appending each item of `list` into the array, same with `...res.Contents`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is using `@aws-sdk/client-s3` and TypeScript, here's an example of pulling all objects from a bucket:

```js
import {
  S3Client,
  ListObjectsV2Command,
  ListObjectsV2CommandInput,
  _Object,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

export const fetchObjects = async (bucket: string) => {
  const objects: _Object[] = [];

  async function fetchObjectsWithPagination(
    bucket: string,
    continuationToken?: ListObjectsV2CommandInput["ContinuationToken"]
  ): Promise<void> {
    const s3 = new S3Client({ region: "YOUR_S3_BUCKET_REGION" });
  
    const result = await s3.send(
      new ListObjectsV2Command({
        Bucket: bucket,
        ContinuationToken: continuationToken,
      })
    );

    objects.push(...(result.Contents || []));
  
    if (result.NextContinuationToken) {
      return fetchObjectsWithPagination(bucket, result.NextContinuationToken);
    }

    return;
  }

  await fetchObjectsWithPagination(bucket);

  return objects;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution as shared by [Mr Jarmod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271415/jarmod) :

```
var params = {
  Bucket: 'mystore.in',
  Delimiter: '/',
  Prefix: '/s/ms.files/',
  Marker:'',
  MaxKeys : 20
};
s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
  else     console.log(data);          
});
```

Comment: It doesn't have any info about pagination