# How to paginate Aws s3 list object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have over 20000 images in s3 and I want to paginate the first 100 after clicking on pagination 2nd link it should load the second 100 images and so on.

```
const params = { Bucket: "test-bucket", Delimiter: '/', MaxKeys: 100, Prefix: "thumbnail_images/Q" };

async function* listAllKeys(params) {
  try {
    do {
      const data = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
      params.ContinuationToken = data.NextContinuationToken;
      yield data;
    } while (params.ContinuationToken);
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

I am using **aws-sdk** node package.

Answer (score 1):

s3 doesn’t provide any pagination feature but you can develop your own.

use s3 get object list to get a list of all images and store it in var imageList.
on first request from UI pass(page:0) the images from imageList[100*0:(100*0)+100]
on second request from UI pass(page:1) the images from imageList[100*1:(100*1)+100]
and so on.

Comment: I have images of over 20000. So how to load all images prefix something?

Comment: see docs: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755129/aws-s3-listobjects-with-pagination

Comment: use listobject method from s3 to get all image names. This will just load the image file name not the images